# Inline Max-Width CSS (Calc W/ Custom Var) Throws W3C Parse Error

Tags: css, inline, var, calc

When I apply the following inline CSS ...

```
<div style="max-width: calc( ( var(--100vh) - 80px ) * .847 );">some content</div>
```

... the W3C validator throws a parse error.

I've peeked at similar issues but they mostly target @media queries, which this is not.

My code now fires using JS instead of pure CSS, which I'd like to change.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The W3C validator is known as not being up to date. The only thing that matters is does it work?

Comment: Fair point, indeed ... but then it's not so out of date that it no longer serves a purpose. Maybe I'll just "measure twice, cut once" that my code is in fact valid, then filter that particular error out of my notifications.